# Separate graphics for different resolutions, android

Tags: android, screen, drawable, resolution

I need drawable resources for different resolutions, such as 320x480, 800x480, 854x480, 800x600
1024x600, 1024x768, 1024x800. It is a game and the scaling of bitmaps is inacceptable, coz they are very sensitive to it. dpi dependent folders and combination with screen sizes(which are deprecated but no other way to set drawable for large screens with same resolution and differend dpi)  are not enaugh. How to distinguish graphics for 1024x600 and 1024x768 for example?

It is so sad to stop use mechanism of auto picking resources and switching to manual loading from assets.
any ideas?

Comment: you can get the resolution at runtime and have different named graphics. that way you can call the correct graphics for whatever resolution the user is running.

Comment: it is workaround, not the solution. I only need different graphics for different resolutions but with the same layout, for example set background="@drawable/background" but different names breake this scheme. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually using 4 resource folders for drawables:

1. drawable-mdpi for 320x480
2. drawable-hdpi for 480x800 and 480x854
3. drawable-large-hdpi for 600x1024, 768x1024 and so on
4. drawable-xlarge-mdpi for 800x1280

These are just enough in my mind. Also, you don't need to worry about different drawable resources for, in example, devices with 800x480 and 854x480 screen sizes: you can specify an offset on the edges of your screen equal to 27 pixels and center your game on the screen. Hope this helps.

Comment: with 1024xXXX a lot of problems coz half of them are recognized as mdpi and some of them as hdpi, for now I use drawable-large-nodpi and xlarge-nodpi, but no way to pick more specific resolution.

Comment: @SaTom, Anyway, it's almost impossible to cover all resolutions, so you've got to work with the most common ones.

Comment: resolutions i specified cover about 95% of target platform, I have no needs to support all resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pixel perfect fit you could always load the background at runtime via a simple method:

```
private void setBackgroundImage() {
   DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
   int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
   int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;

   // TODO: Conditional Structure to apply the right drawable 
   // ressource to be applied in the background

}
```

After you've acquired the resolution of the display you can apply the appropriate background via the [`setBackgroundDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setBackgroundDrawableResource%28int%29) method.

Comment: I know this variant, but it was so good to make ui totally independent from logic. But with this hack I also will loose preview of layout in eclipse, usually I write xml in xml editor but preview helps a lot in ui building.